# Physics vs. Keyframes

Tags: physics, keyframes

I am just starting out doing animation with keyframes so far.

I got a little bit confused with the following things and how they behave to each other.

We can make something move via Keyframes and Physics.  I feel like when I want to make an animation I simply don't know which part of blender I need to use.

I know, it's a very generic question but most of the tutorials just go into detail and don't really give an overview.

Answer (score 1):

Keyframes for animation, and if you want something like a ball realistically falling, then that's when you use physics. Physics isn't used often, and is much more complicated than animation. I would suggest sticking to animation for now, and going into physics when you are more comfortable with it. Watch some tutorials on Youtube to help you.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I did help, thank you!
If I need physics and animation you usually start with physics and then bake them into keyframes, right?
Where does rigging belong in the physics/Animation context?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, blender does math to make a physics simulation, records the object with physics location every frame, and turns that into keyframes when you bake it so you can edit each frame. Rigging is definitely not physics, rather it is using the location of objects (bones) to move a mesh.

If you want to animate an object with physics, there is a checkbox that allows you to do that

When rigging, you paint on a mesh how much you want to move a mesh in what areas. So if you wanted to rig a finger, you paint the finger with a heavy weight, and you paint the joint with a lighter one so the bone behind it has an influence too.

Animation has no rules. You are not limited to anything. Physics limits you to - well - the laws of physics.  This is why animation is used more commonly than physics, but physics is helpful at times too.

Comment: That was pretty much what I was looking for, thanks for the clear answer! Animation with keyframes is common in combination with Body constraints, right?